# Moving to another frame in the same page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, frame

I'm really a beginner in javaScript and HTML .. I have created a web page with two buttons, depending on which button is pressed I want to open a different form. How can I do it ?

When the user presses the first button which is "S&P Database" the browser should transfer him to another form that contains a list of choices. But when he presses the Generate report button another different choices should appear to him .. But here I don't want to open a new window I need it in the same window but using different page inside the browser ..

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> My System </h1>


<form action="">
<input type="button" value="S & P Database ">
<input type="button" value="Generate Report  ">



</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a question a bit clearly?

Comment: I did already, I hope it is now clear

Comment: I'd recommend spending a few hours going through the W3Schools HTML and Javascript tutorials, http://w3schools.com/html/default.asp and http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iframe in the page

```
<iframe name="myiframe" id="myiframe"></iframe>
```

then you from set target to that iframe

```
<form target="myiframe" action="....">
```

Comment: So in the same php file that I created htdocs folder I will add these line of code or should I create another new php for each iframe

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways !

You can load both of them, and [show the one you need with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413042/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-select-using-jquery).
Or you can use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).