# Modify Existing Questions answer

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Just a quick questions. Im new to this site but this link [Show/Hide multiple DIVs with Select using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413042/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-select-using-jquery)

I just wanted to know how to change the code so its not in a drop down select but an actual link.

If anyone could help me that would be badass!!

I have looked everywhere and this is closest to what i could find.

Thanks everyone. Woot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the accepted answer from this question [how to show/hide divs by select.(jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043267/how-to-show-hide-divs-by-select-jquery) the question the OP linked just so he could see the similarities between doing the two. As it was pointed out this naming convention is not good at all.

**Markup**

```
<a id="1" href="#">Link one</a>
<a id="2" href="#">Link two</a>
<a id="3" href="#">Link three</a>


<div id="div1">content here 1</div>
<div id="div2">content here 2</div>
<div id="div3">content here 3</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#div1, #div2, #div3').hide();

    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#div1, #div2, #div3').hide();
       $('#div' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    });
}
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/kJGcE/

And here is a better way

**Markup**

```
<a class="divHide" href="#">Link one</a>
<a class="divHide" href="#">Link two</a>
<a class="divHide" href="#">Link three</a>


<div class="divShow">content here 1</div>
<div class="divShow">content here 2</div>
<div class="divShow">content here 3</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('a.divHide').click(function() {
   $('.divShow').hide();
   $('.divShow').eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/kJGcE/2/

Comment: oh thanks soo much for the quick turn around man, that's badass. im also trying to make it load up one to start up with rather than start with none at all.

Comment: @Reigal I know your totally right, I modified the code that was the accepted answer from his linked question. Ill update my answer with that as well.

Comment: @Loktar - yeah I got you. But if you're up to getting more points, give good practice answers. Or even if you're not up to the points, please still do give good practice. It will help us all towards better web experience... cheers! :D

Comment: Alright @Reigal I provided 2 answers, one with a slightly better way imo. You talked me into it :P

Comment: @loktar: bruv i put these code in and it doesnt seem to be working? i definately have the jquery js refferenced in the code and it just lists them under eachother? rather than showing one at a time?

Comment: Make sure to add it to your page like so $(function(){ //Code here});

Comment: yeah i see that in here. still doesnt seem to be working? i literally just copied what you have in this answer and pasted it in a new html page with the jquery refferenced in it.

Comment: there all still just listing there but are hiding all of them if i click any of the links? Sorry have i screwed up? Sorr for the hassle man!

Comment: @loktar thanks for all your help so far man, its been awesome, but just cant get it working. i literally copied in pasted in your code from this website and tried from the demo, i also put in the $function(){ code here  }); and it just lists them and the links dont work. Sorry im not complaining, its just doin my head in.

Comment: @jake, is the demo not working for you? or just the ones you have copied?

Comment: hey thanks man, well when i go to the demo it works. But when i copy and paste the code in there it doesnt work. I took loktar's advice and put the $function(){ lokars code here}); and it doesnt work? I got the latest firefox I just cant get it to work properly? The links dont really do anything. Its as if the content is static and doesnt do anything? Is there a way that i can show you what my code looks like? Thanks again for your help man!

Comment: @Jake - you can paste your codes here at http://jsfiddle.net/ then after saving it, you can give the link for us to see...

Comment: @reigel thansk heaps of your help man http://jsfiddle.net/KNbQZ/ Thats pretty much what i need it to do. Just preview a list of regions in a table (only links) then when you click on them it changes the visibility of the Div so you can only see that specific Region. Thanks man!

Comment: @jake - here's an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/KNbQZ/1/) . I just hope you are using jQuery version 1.4 or higher...

Comment: @Reigal after all that extra work you should get points and the answer imo.