# Jquery: Show a hidden div based on the Value of a select form option

Tags: jquery, forms, html, hide, show

I am terrible at Jquery, and can barely understand it as I try to make this code for my site.

My goal is to have *Div* tags appear when the value that is selected in a form equals that *Div* tag's name.

Here is what I have:

```
<form>
    <select name="SELECT_Mood_30">
        <option value="hap">Happy</option>
        <option value="sad">Sadness</option>
        <option value="ang">Angry</option>
        <option value="gru">Grumpy</option>
    </select>

    <select name="SELECT_hair_75">
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="bla">black</option>
        <option value="blo">blonde</option>
        <option value="bru">brunette</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Now imagine there's maybe 40, 50, or even 100 different options. Each with a hidden div like below. Upon selecting the option with a value that matches the name of one of these divs, I want the div to appear. When deselecting it I want it to disappear.

```
<div id="ang" style="display:none;">
    SO YOU'RE ANGRY HUH?!
</div>
<div id="sad" style="display:none;">
    How can I make you feel better?
</div>
<div id="bla" style="display:none;">
    Black hair is really cool
</div>
<div id="red" style="display:none;">
    Red hair is nice!
</div>
```

Is it possible in Jquery to make this? Possibly make it look up the value that is selected, then unhide the named div. The name of the form doesn't matter, it could look up the color red in the mood form and if it appears it could display it anyway. If the named div doesn't exist, then nothing happens and all is good? (no error message or anything)

I've found a few working ones online, but they all seem to require to put each option inside the Jquery, which is what I don't want. I would like it to be flexible enough where you simply have to change the option values and the div names.

Edit: I forgot to mention that say if one select is chosen, such as "sad", and then someone chooses "red", I don't want the div that was named "sad" to disappear. but if the "ang" option is selected, I want the "sad" to disappear. I hope that doesn't confuse things a lot more.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043267/how-to-show-hide-divs-by-select-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413042/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-select-using-jquery

Comment: Also, I would add a class `tip` or something with style `display:none`. That will save you from inline CSS and also make it easier to hide all divs at once `$('.tip').hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to all of your div

```
$("select").change(
function()
{
$(".class").hide();
$(".class[id='"+this.value+"']").show();
})
```

Comment: This doesn't hide the other divs: "When deselecting it I want it to disappear."

Comment: Dont let div to hide there may be someother div also...try giving it a class and hide

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble he changed the question from names to ids :)

Comment: Thank you! This works ALMOST perfect. Now I am trying to make it so if I select "red", then I select "ang", the div IDed as "red" wont disappear. I giving each group of divs their own seperate classes, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Give all your divs (hidden) a class say `class='foo'`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
    $('.foo').hide();

    $("div[name='"+$(this).val()+"']").show();

    });
    });
```

Comment: $(document).ready() is necessary only if you plan to put your code on the <head> of the page, which is not advisable (it will slow the display of the page contents)

Comment: @Pablo document.ready is triggered once DOM is ready, is there anything we can do before the DOM gets ready(other than document.write)? And is it advisable not to wait till the DOM is ready? Can you explain your point? I have understood DOMready this way.

Comment: @sabithpocker Whenever the browser sees a script tag, it stops rendering the page until it is loaded and interpreted. If the script is big, this can be an appreciable ammount of time. If you relegate your scripts to the bottom of the page, not only are you sure they will fire when the DOM is ready, but the page itself will show up in the browser window faster. Have a look here->http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Comment: @Pablo that was interesting to read, thank you for the link to crockford views. But I think that applies to external javascript files mainly, "An in-page <script> does not have a significant impact on loading time" is what crockford says

Comment: @Pablo if you load the scripts at the end you only optimize the wait for document write, but your browser could trigger the evaluation of the JavaScript before the DOM is ready (being at the end doesn't means that the DOM is ready). It's a common practice of jQuery to use jQuery(function(){}) (a shortcut for $(document).ready) if you want to do something when the DOM is available. This presentation explain some of the complexities of script loading: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/The-Once-And-Future-Script-Loader

Comment: @Diego How is jQuery(function(){}) a shortcut for document.ready? How can the DOM not be ready if you reach the bottom of the page (meaning it has been parsed)? If you could point me at an example (jsfiddle mb?) I would appreciate it. I'm not searching for an argument, I'm just surprised.

Comment: @Pablo about jQuery(function(){}) is on the jQuery docs for the ready event (http://api.jquery.com/ready/ see the part that says "All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:..."). About the ready state, I cannot point you to an specific document. But each engine Gecko, WebKit, Trident had they own assumptions about when the DOM is considered ready, and there is no guarantee that by putting the script at the end the DOM will be ready (google for document readiness and jQuery, you'll find that there were lot of bugs caused by that odd diferences between browsers)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
jQuery(function() {

   $('select').change(function() {
       // I've use .message to distinguish the divs to show or hide

       var value = $(this).val();
       $('div.message').each(function() { 
              $(this).toggle($(this).attr('id') == value) 
       })

   });

});
```